# Is this proper usage of IDisposable?

Tags: c#, idisposable

I have a FTP class which has a `Dipose()` method

```
public class Ftp : IFtp
    {
        //other methods, properties and fields

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_ftp.IsConnected)
                _ftp.Close();

            _ftp.Dispose();
            _ftp = null;
        }
    }
```

This is the interface I am using for accessing the `Ftp` class

```
public interface IFtp : IDisposable
    {
        //other methods signatures
        void Dispose();
    }
```

Is this a proper and functional way of disposing the content used by `Ftp`?

Comment: What is _ftp?  Can you give us some idea of what you are concerned about not working.

Comment: Adding null check for `_ftp` may be a good idea.

Comment: `_ftp` is an instance of `FTPConnection` from `edtFTPnet`, also, `_ftp` is never going to be null.

Comment: @BrunoKlein, you set it to null yourself.  If a client calls Dispose twice, you probably don't want a null reference exception--though you could throw an ObjectDisposedException at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume _ftp is an IDisposable object. If so, it should be enough to do the follwing:

```
public class Ftp : IFtp
{
    //other methods, properties and fields

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _ftp.Dispose();    
    }
}
```

also

```
public interface IFtp : IDisposable
{
    //other methods signatures    
}
```

That is, you do not need to re-specify the `Dispose()` method (in your interface) if your interface inherits from `IDisposable`, as it's already specified in `IDisposable`.

Comment: you should add sealed to the class.

Answer (score 3):

That works fine for the regular use of the class. However, you should check if the `_ftp` reference is null before you start to access it. Common practice is that you should be able to call the `Dispose` method more than once without causing any harm.

You might also want to add a Finalizer to the class, where you can dispose it in case of the one using the class fails to dispose of it properly for some reason.

The coding example in the documentation for the [`IDisposable` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IDisposable.aspx) is quite complete and well commented.

Comment: I thought so, since it is working, but `Code Analysis` said I should do proper usage of `IDisposable`. "CA1063 Implement IDisposable correctly Provide an overridable implementation of Dispose(bool) on 'Ftp' or mark the type as sealed. A call to Dispose(false) should only clean up native resources. A call to Dispose(true) should clean up both managed and native resources."

Comment: A finalized would be improper if you are just encapsulating another class that implements IDisposable, since that class will already have a finalizer if necessary.

Comment: @BrunoKlein, you should follow that guidance.  Hopefully, you can just mark your class as sealed.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the finaliser. @MattSmith Because the finalizer is not part of the IDisposable interface, there's no guarantee it has already been implemented (or implemented properly) by the encapsulated class. Your assertion that finalizers will already be present is _very likely_ to be correct for the Framework BCL, but not necessarily so for other classes implementing IDisposable, for example some home grown or third party IFtp interface, where indeed the _point_ of this encapsulation might be to include missing or improved finalization.

Answer (score 2):

Refer [MSDN documentation for `IDisposable` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) generally.

The [MSDN `IDisposable.Dispose()` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) specifically states:

> When implementing this method, ensure that all held resources are
>   freed by propagating the call through the containment hierarchy. For
>   example, if an object A allocates an object B, and object B allocates
>   an object C, then A's Dispose implementation must call Dispose on B,
>   which must in turn call Dispose on C. An object must also call the
>   Dispose method of its base class if the base class implements
>   IDisposable.

...which is what you're doing.

For detail about your design warning, refer [MSDN CA1063: Implement IDisposable correctly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms244737.aspx).

Assuming your underlying FTP implementation is not managed, you *should* also include a finalizer, if one is not already present in the base implementation. The [MSDN `IDisposable.Dispose()` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) specifically states:

> Because the Dispose method must be called explicitly, objects that
>   implement IDisposable must also implement a finalizer to handle
>   freeing resources when Dispose is not called.

Refer also [MSDN `Object.Finalize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx) and [MSDN Implementing Finalize and Dispose to Clean Up Unmanaged Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx)

If there's no appropriate finalizer in your inheritance chain somewhere, perhaps this is the reason for your warning?

Note also (as a counter example) that Microsoft recommends that *consumers* shouldn't call `Dispose()` directly.  [MSDN `using` statement documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) states:

> As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and
>   instantiate it in a using statement.

The preferred approach for *consumers* is to "use" an `IDisposable` resource, like this:

```
   using (FTP myDisposableFTP = new FTP()) {
     ...
   }
```

This is basically "syntactic sugar" to ensure that the `Dispose()` method is called when you're done using your disposable resource (ie the end of the `using` block), or importantly, if an exception occurs *within* the `using` block.

This pattern also avoids the requirement for `null` checks on your instance reference, as the instance has been constructed at the start of the block. It also ensures the object can't be reassigned (protecting the underlying resource from being accidentally left open, even when your original reference goes out of scope).

But I think it's doubtful that you could incorporate this pattern (or an equivalent try/catch/finally) into your inheritance/interface implementation, though.

So yes, calling the `Dispose()` method is functionally Ok, so long as you remember to call it under all circumstances where it is required (eg in your exception handling), or where you're re-exposing that out to your consumers to properly handle as part of a "wrapped" `IDisposable` implementation. But you should also add a finalizer if your resource is unmanaged.